# using function in node js

Tags: node.js, function

```
a)  Write an integer function Input as follows:

         function Input(s)

The function takes in a String parameter that will be used as part of the input  prompt, e.g. "Please enter 1st integer" and "Please enter 2nd integer". It returns an integer value corresponding to the user input.           

b)  Write a function bigger that takes in 2 integer values first and second. It compares which number is bigger and returns one of the following string values:
            "1st number is bigger"
            "2nd number is bigger"
            "The 2 numbers are equal"

c)  In the main part of the program, invoke Input(“1st”) and Input(“2nd”) to get the values of first and second. Invoke bigger and display the string returned.
```

I encountered some problem with my code as it doesn't seem to work as i do not know how to link the inputs together. This is one of my practical questions.

i tried linking the input together but i am unsure of how to do it because the question is kind of confusing.

i do not know how to describe my problem as i do not quite understand the question requirements

Comment: It's impossible to help you unless you mention what language you're programming in. Add it as a tag.

Comment: Why do you think you need to use a callback? The requirements don't mention anything about that.

Comment: then how do you go about doing it? i am using nodejs thanks for highlighting

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I suspect that you're overthinking this.

According to the description, your main program doesn't need to be more complicated than this:

```
let a = Input("1st");
let b = Input("2nd");
console.log(bigger(a, b));
```

Now, you "just" need to implement `Input` and `bigger`.

---

Addendum: putting the code you already have in functions is not very complicated:

```
function Input(prompt)
{
    return parseInt(input.question("Please enter " + prompt + " number:"));
}

function bigger(a, b)
{
    if (a > b) {
        return "1st number is bigger";
    }
    else if (a < b) {
        return "2nd number is bigger";
    }
    else {
        return "The two numbers are equal";
    }
}
```

Use with the code above.

Comment: then how do you use function to implement it? i am using readline-sync for response in the terminal.what are the steps to take to implement the program?

Comment: In that case, `Input` will basically just be a call to `readlineSync.questionInt`. Or are you wondering how to write a function, any function?

Comment: i am only able to use "readline-sync". is it possible for you to show me the code for doing it? using var and console.log?     var num1 = parseInt(input.question("Please enter 1st number: "));
    var num2 = parseInt(input.question("Please enter 2nd number: "));
    if (num1>num2) {
        console.log("num1 number is bigger. ")
    } 
    else if (num2>num1) {
        console.log("num2 number is bigger. ")
    }
    else {
    console.log("Both numbers are equal.")
    }